# MySQL database structure for multiple users with 100s to 1000s of unique rows each

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-design

I am currently working on developing a website that allows users to manage items in their "pantry", "recipe book", "meal plan", and "shopping cart".  As each one of these tables can house a large number of unique items, and each is unique to the user, is it more efficient to create new tables for each user, or to simply log the user's ID with each entry in each table?

I ask because I can see a table of 1,000+ pantry items split across 20 users, where hunting for all of them by id may be more costly than simply finding that users table and displaying all the results.

Or is there some other third option I'm not even considering?

Any/all help is appreciated. If more information is needed, please ask.

Comment: With appropriate indexes, a single table should be fine.

Comment: NEVER do what you're suggesting. EVER!

Comment: And per-user tables will make it difficult to write general queries across all users. And do you really expect to only ever have 20 users?

Comment: One table. Bah! 1 table per vital element.

Comment: Alright, I get the message. Haha. I have no formal education on databases, and I appreciate the help (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create 1 database, a table for Users (that houses their 'unique ID' and meta info), then a separate table for each area (pantry items, recipes, etc) that is associated with the unique ID.

Users:

```
ID|Username|Password|RealName....
 1|Jojo    | *******|Joseph
```

Recipes:

```
ID|Username|Name            |Ingredients    |Prep....
 1|Jojo    |Chicken Tarag.. | 1 pound of... |Prepare ....
```

**Eazy-peazy.**

Comment: Realized it from the comments, but thank you for posting an answer. Hopefully this helps future "Googlers"